# How to Integrate Dependency check report.html from Bamboo to Sonarqube 6.7.2

Tags: maven, sonarqube, bamboo

I am trying to integrate dependency check report.html(site-report-html/dependency-check-report.html) which is at bamboo artifacts section but after the build is successful I don't see the dependency check count on sonarqube(sonar dependency check plugin is installed on sonarqube), can someone please advise. Thanks.

Comment: <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
 </plugin>
   <plugin>
   <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
   <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.5</version>
   <configuration>
       <format>ALL</format>
       <outputDirectory>${dependency.check.report.dir}</outputDirectory>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>

Comment: I can see the dependency check report.html on my bamboo build but I don't see the dependency check report on sonarqube, can someone please advise to show the dependency check report on sonarqube dashboard? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to import your Dependency Check report, you'll need a SonarQube plugin capable of reading the report and feeding it to SonarQube.

[dependency-check-sonar-plugin](https://github.com/stevespringett/dependency-check-sonar-plugin) seems to fit the bill, altho I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Hi, nice, that is official from OWASP dependecy check, after installation there is new widget available at sonarqube dashboard- "Known Vulnerabilities in Dependencies"

Comment: Hi Ann, latest sonar-dependency-check-plugin-1.1.0.jar has been installed on sonarqube 6.7.2 and I don't see the metrics on sonarqube at OWSAP measures, it displays empty metrics